# Import and formatting multiple files from excel in R

Tags: r

1. I would like to import multiple files .xlsx from one path.

**I used for it:**

`mayflies = list.files(pattern="*.xlsx",full.names = T)`

The function bellow allows create a large list by one sheet in common.

```
tst = lapply(mayflies, function (i){
x= read_excel(i,sheet = 1)
x$file = 1

x

}]
```

2. I would like now combine all list files as only one data frame

**I could just use this code above:**

```
tst = do.call("rbind.data.frame", tst)
```

the problem is:

First, I have a header (23 rows), and I would like to extract just one piece of information in row=3 and column =1 and paste it into one new column.

The second problem is that the names of the columns start only in row = 24, and I would need to remove rows 1:23 but first grab the information in the header.

Could someone help me with this question?

In final, I would like to get one dataset containing all excel files by columns names and add a new column with one piece of information extracted from the header.

Comment: Did you meant `lapply` instead of `apply`?.  With `read_excel`, you can use `skip = 23` to skip the first 23 rows

Comment: Thank you, I did correct the question. Yes, but first I would like to grab the information in row 3 and column 1 from header, could you suggest something please?

Comment: There is a `range` option as well i.e. according to documentation `A cell range to read from, as described in cell-specification. Includes typical Excel ranges like "B3:D87"`.  Perhaps this should be two calls, i.e. one to get the row3/column1 and second call to get the data without the first 23 lines

Comment: Could you give one example to get the row3/column 1? sorry, I am beginner.